# Change the state of a Sketch without destroying it (ArcGIS API for JavaScript and React)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-react

I'm working on an application that the user defines a point on a map and then goes on to take that point's information to do other stuff. Originally, this has been done by having an event listener grab a mapPoint event when the user clicks on the map. However, I needed to implement snapping, so I refactored it to use an Esri Sketch instead. The snapping works really well and I'm able to pass the point information to the proper function and let it be on its way.

However! Suddenly, my branch is experiencing a serious slowdown, often to the point of my browser alerting me that the page is unresponsive. After some testing, I found that the slowdown does not happen if I use the destroy() method on the Sketch, but this just ends up causing other issues since the Sketch defined in the component's constructor and there is a great possibility of needing to re-use the Sketch multiple times.

I checked the state of the Sketch at various points. When the component is built, the Sketch is defined in the constructor and it's state is "disabled". The state changes to "ready" when you create a graphic. The state is still coming back as "ready" when you use .cancel() on the Sketch. The only way I've figured out how to change the Sketch's state back to "disabled" is by using that .destroy() method.

Is there another way to disable the Sketch without destroying it's instance?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions here are expected to contain code. Please [Edit] your Question.